# Closed form for the Stirling numbers of the second kind.

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

I have realized through inspection that ${n \brace 2}=2^{n-1}-1$ and I have figured out with the help of Pedro Tamaroff that ${n \brace 3}=\frac{1}{6}(3^{n}-3\cdot2^n+3)$. For what other values of $k$ can we do a similar characterization of ${n \brace k}$? can we do it for all positive integers?

Comment: One of the first things both wikipedia and mathworld mention is the formula ${n\brace k} = \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^i{k\choose i}(k-i)^n.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: taken with an [appropriate index](http://oeis.org/A048993), the Stirling numbers of the second kind form the exponential Riordan array $[1, e^x - 1]$. (See e.g. P. Barry, [Generalized Stirling Numbers, Exponential Riordan Arrays, and Toda Chain Equations](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL17/Barry1/barry263.html), Journal of Integer Sequences, 17 (2014)).